# Wordpress API Insert article?

Tags: php, wordpress, api

How i can insert article in a Wordpress Blog from an external website with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enabling XML-RPC: XML-RPC functionality is turned on by default since WordPress 3.5. In previous versions of WordPress, XML-RPC was user enabled. To enable, go to Settings > Writing > Remote Publishing and check the checkbox. More: http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support